# High probability the Chandrian die in "Doors of Stone"

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle

Something came up my mind, when I read "A Wise Mans Fear". Shehyn tells Kvothe the story of seven cities and one city, another variant of the creation war stories. This is under the condition that Kvothe does not ask question afterwards, and that he doesn't mention it until he has walked a thousand miles and slept a thousand nights. This is to avoid confrontation with the Chandrian, as mentioning their names works like a tracking device. ([source](http://kkc.wikia.com/wiki/Shehyn))

But Kvothe does speak their names out load a couple of time, when he tells his story.

- Haliax and Cinder, when he encounters the Candrian after they murdered his family
- Cinder, when he has flashbacks about the mentioned event
- Cinder, when re recognizes, that it was him at the Bandit Camp

Those Names are written down in the book, which means he speaks them out loud while telling his because the Deevan is not allowed to change a single word.

So he isn't afraid of them anymore? My conclusion is, he killed or some kind of imprisoned the Chandrian by the time he tells his story.

So my question is:
Could my conclusion be correct or am I missing something? Or could there be other reasons for what he is doing?

P.S. I will try to quote some passages, as soon as possible, but since I didn't read the book in English, I need to find the English text passages.

Comment: Are you asking a question or looking for a discussion here?  If the former, what exactly is the question?

Comment: A little bit of both, I will edit my post: I want to know, if I miss something here, or if my conclusion could be true. Or if there could be another reason

Comment: Although it's enormously long, you might enjoy reading through the archives of this Tor-sponsored analytic reread of the two books: http://www.tor.com/features/series/patrick-rothfuss-reread.  This particular point came up, I recall, along with a hundred other things you probably never thought of.

Comment: @RyanReich Thanks! That's a really nice to read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> "I have slept my thousand nights and travelled several thousand miles since then, Bast. It is safe to say them once. With all the hell that's breaking loose in the world these days you can believe people are telling old stories more often. If the Chandrian are listening for names I don't doubt they've got a slow din of whispering a from Arueh to the Centhe Sea." - p. 846 Wise Mans Fear

To me, this implies that the Chandrian are still alive in the 'present' day of the books, meaning they won't be killed during the Doors of Stone, or at least not during Kvothe's story.

Comment: This truly slipped out of my mind, thanks!

Comment: That was the quote to which I was referring. This is the right answer!

Answer (score 10):

Kvothe says their names, not their *Names*. Therefore, there's no evidence that any Chandrian die in the next book. The explicit takeaway of the story with his parents is that they accidentally discovered the Names of the Chandrian.

However, I'd say that this sort of question doesn't really fit the format of this site. This is a speculative question while this site is much more about factual questions.

Comment: So you believe Kvothes father discovered they real *Names*, when he was writing his song. I would add some more infos to discuss this further, but if you say this isn't the right place to do so, can you recommend a platform where I can?

Comment: It's explicitly in the second book, when he learns that snippet about the Chandrian from the Adem.

Answer (score -2):

As rsegal says, Kvothe uses their small names throughout the telling of his story with one exception, when he speaks of the Ademre song.  Cyphus, Stercus, Ferule, Usnea, Dalcenti, Alenta and Alaxel are their *Real Names*.

Kvothe says:

> No. Names are the key. Real Names. Deep names. And I have been avoiding them for just that reason.